# ng-view scope communicating with main scope communication

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It's maybe a stupid question but it's late and i'm desperate.
I have a angularjs application that uses ngRoute. But everything is done in one controller. Now I have a form in a view and the use of that form is to put it's input field data into a var to send with post.

Don't mind al the console log i'm trying to find the error.

**APP.JS**

`

```
    $scope.addDevice = function(){
        $scope.device = {};

        var data = {

            'Name' : $scope.device.ChildName,
            'Serial' : $scope.device.Serial

        };

        console.log($scope.device.Serial);
        console.log($scope.device.ChildName);
        console.log(data);

        $http.post('http://141.135.5.117:3500/device/register', data, { headers: headers })
        .then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            console.log(headers);




        });


    }`
```

**Settings.html ( Note: this is a view in ng-view)**

```
<form role="form" class='userForm'>
            <label for="addDevice">Add Device</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="deviceserial" placeholder="Enter serial number" ng-model="$scope.device.Serial">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Devicechildname" placeholder="Enter baby name" ng-model="$scope.device.ChildName">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" ng-click="addDevice()">Add Device</button>
            <p>{{$scope.device.Serial}}</p>

</form>
```

**This is the console output**

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aRLw.png)

All the functions are done in one controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Remove $scope from ng-model="$scope.device.Serial"
and define $scope.device = {}; outside  $scope.addDevice = function(){

$scope.device = {};

$scope.addDevice = function(){
-- you code here --
}

Working code example

```js
angular.module('inputExample', [])
   .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http) {
     $scope.val = '1';
     $scope.device = {};
     
     $scope.addDevice = function(){        

        var data = {
            'Name' : $scope.device.ChildName,
            'Serial' : $scope.device.Serial
        };

        console.log($scope.device.Serial);
        console.log($scope.device.ChildName);
        console.log(data);
        $http.post('http://141.135.5.117:3500/device/register', data)
        .then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            console.log(headers);
        });
    }
     
     
     
   }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="inputExample">
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">

<form role="form" class='userForm'>
            <label for="addDevice">Add Device</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="deviceserial" placeholder="Enter serial number" ng-model="device.Serial">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Devicechildname" placeholder="Enter baby name" ng-model="device.ChildName">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" ng-click="addDevice()">Add Device</button>
            <p>{{device.Serial}}</p>
</form>

</div>
</div>
```